# how to select top 1 data order by date in sql and sqlite

Tags: sql-server-2008

My data is like that

```
Name   code   start_date   end_date    price 
shop1  7001   2013-01-01   9999-12-31  200 
shop1  7001   2015-12-01   9999-12-31  300 
shop1  7110   2015-05-25   9999-12-31  800 
shop1  7120   2015-05-25   9999-12-31  700 
shop1  7130   2013-01-01   9999-12-31  300
```

I would like to select top 1 data order by start_date in all data with one query.

```
Name   code   start_date   end_date    price 
shop1  7001   2015-12-01   9999-12-31  300 
shop1  7110   2015-05-25   9999-12-31  800 
shop1  7120   2015-05-25   9999-12-31  700 
shop1  7130   2013-01-01   9999-12-31  300
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.code, t1.start_date, t1.end_date, t1.price
FROM prices t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT code, MAX(start_date) AS maxDate
    FROM prices
    GROUP BY code
) t2
ON t1.code = t2.code AND t1.start_date = t2.maxDate
ORDER BY t1.start_date DESC
```